# sbt direct git source dependency - not fetching transitive library dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying out sbt's direct `dependsOn` feature with a git repository ("project A") hosted at Github. I am using a stable tag reference, and in my test project ("project B"), sbt *does* clone project A from source and starts compiling. However compilation fails with project A's own dependencies seemingly missing (i.e. it doesn't seem to pick up anything defined in project A's `build.sbt`).

Is this a different from maven/ivy managed dependencies? Do I need to include all the transitive dependencies in my child project B? Sounds a bit weird to me. That would kind of kill off the whole effort, as I'm having like a dozen libraries on which project A depends.

---

To illustrate:

**Project A** (online on Github as source):

```
// build.sbt:
version := "1.2.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.foo" %% "bar" % "1.0"
```

**Project B** (local):

```
// project/Build.scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object Build extends sbt.Build {
  lazy val projA = RootProject(uri("git://github.com/me/projA.git#v1.2.3"))

  lazy val projB = Project(id = "project-B", base = file(".").dependsOn(projA)
}
```

This goes:

```
[info] Compiling 678 Scala sources to /Users/me/.sbt/staging/
  5666eafa865fdf605be3/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /Users/me/.sbt/staging/5666eafa865fdf605be3/src/main/scala/com/me/
  BarKeeper.scala:3: not found: object bar
[error] import org.foo.bar
[error]        ^
```

So do I have to re-declare the library dependency on `"org.foo" %% "bar" % "1.0"`? I hope not!

Comment: I used this feature in a few projects and never had this issue. Suggestions: ensure build.sbt is in the root; make a Build.scala and declare the dependencies there. Of course, I am assuming you can forking the project A is not a big deal.

Comment: @pedrofurla ok, so this is good news first, because it should in theory work. I do have `build.sbt` in root, and there is no separate `project/Build.scala` for project A. So it must be some glitch in sbt, I guess? Could `retrievedManaged := true` be a problem (I use it in every project, because that's the only way I can sensibly oversee library versions and snapshots versus stable stuff)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was purely my own fault, not sbt's. I had overseen an **unmanaged library** (folder `lib`) in project A. After exchanging it for a Maven managed version (folder `lib_managed`), project A now correctly compiles from source in the staging for project B.